# obtener valores de un rango con openpyxl python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Con la librería openpyxl , estoy tatando de leer los datos de una hoja, sin contar la primera fila, ya he podido leer el rango, pero no logro capturar el valor, alguno sabe con esta librería cómo se puede hacer?

```
rango = MiHoja['A1':'E'+str(MiHoja.max_column)]
```

Comment: Mejor usa pandas

Comment: El problema es que no puedo usarlo :(

Comment: Hice las siguientes pruebas con el rango: type(rango), type(rango[0]) y ambas devuelven que se trata de tuplas. Cada item de las tuplas es un [objeto Cell](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell) (cuyo valor se obtiene con .value). En conclusión es una simple tupla que contiene cada fila del rango y cada item de la fila es el valor. Solo te queda iterar sobre eso. Si muestras el rango en tu consola con print, vas a ver a lo que me refiero.

Answer (score 0):

Interando las celdas que componen el rango que seleccionado, en este ejemplo 'A1:B10' :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = "NombrePlanilla.xlsx",  read_only=False)
sheet_ranges = wb['SheetName']

rango = sheet_ranges['A1:B10']
for rangocell in rango:
    for cell in rangocell:
        print( "celda :", cell.column_letter, cell.row, "valor celda :", cell.value )
        # resultado 1er Print "celda : A 1 valor celda : NombreProveedor"
```